Power automate: The resolved string values for the following parameters are invalid
I'm trying to create an app on power apps using power automate, my data is on dataverse and here is the deal.
On my app I have a form that you can fill with client, equipment, serial number, etc.
One of that fields is engineer. My idea is that, when you have a task with an engineer assigned, power-automate sends an email.
But when you don't have the engineer assigned, sends an email to me.
Issue
My flow works great by the branch of false in my condition, that is when I select the engineer. But when my condition is true, and the engineer is not selected, the condition fails.
The error shown on power-automate:

My condition on my workflow:

What I tried
I tried creating the condition with the id of engineer being equal to null. I left that field  blank, I created more Call Id options, but nothing works.
